# Почему переменным из enum присваиваются неверные значения

Tags: java

Имеется класс `Food`, в котором имеется перечисление `Ration`:

```
public class Food {
    private Ration  ration[] = Ration.values();       // Возвращаем массив, содержищий список констант типа Ration

public void getValue(){
        for(int i = 0; i < ration.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Имя: " + ration[i].getName());
            System.out.println("Состояние: " + ration[i].getInclude() + "\n");
        }
    }

// Конструктор
    public Food(boolean breakfast, boolean lunch, boolean dinner, boolean supper, boolean alcohol){
        ration[0].setInclude(breakfast);
        ration[1].setInclude(lunch);
        ration[2].setInclude(dinner);
        ration[3].setInclude(supper);
        ration[4].setInclude(alcohol);
        setTotalCost();
    }
}

// Дневной рацион
enum Ration{
    // Завтрак
    BREAKFAST{
        String  name = "Завтрак";
        boolean include = false;
        int     cost    = 10;

        @Override
        public void setInclude(boolean value){
            include = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getInclude() {
            return include;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCost(){
            return cost;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    },

    // Обед
    LUNCH{
        String  name = "Обед";
        boolean include = false;
        int     cost    = 11;

        @Override
        public void setInclude(boolean value){
            include = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getInclude() {
            return include;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCost(){
            return cost;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    },

    // Ужин
    DINNER{
        String  name = "Ужин";
        boolean include = false;
        int     cost    = 12;

        @Override
        public void setInclude(boolean value){
            include = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getInclude() {
            return include;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCost(){
            return cost;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    },

    // Прием пищи перед сном
    SUPPER{
        String  name = "Прием пищи перед сном";
        boolean include = false;
        int     cost    = 13;

        @Override
        public void setInclude(boolean value){
            include = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getInclude() {
            return include;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCost(){
            return cost;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    },

    // Алкоголь
    ALCOHOL{
        String  name = "Алкоголь";
        boolean include = false;
        int     cost    = 14;

        @Override
        public void setInclude(boolean value){
            include = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getInclude() {
            return include;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCost(){
            return cost;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    };

    public abstract void    setInclude(boolean value);  // включить в ассортимент
    public abstract boolean getInclude();               // получить состояние включения в ассортимент
    public abstract int     getCost();                  // получить стоимость отдельных пунктов рациона
    public abstract String  getName();                  // получить тип рациона
}
```

В классе `Main` создаю экземпляр класса `Food`:

```
        Food food0 = new Food(false, false, false, false, false);
        Food food1 = new Food(true, false, false, false, false);
        Food food2 = new Food(true, true, false, false, false);
        Food food3 = new Food(true, true, true, false, false);
        Food food4 = new Food(true, true, true, true, false);
        Food food5 = new Food(true, true, true, true, true);
```

Почему при вызове метода `getValue()` класса `Food` я получаю все `true`?

```
Имя: Завтрак
Состояние: true

Имя: Обед
Состояние: true

Имя: Ужин
Состояние: true

Имя: Прием пищи перед сном
Состояние: true

Имя: Алкоголь
Состояние: true
```

**Ответ:**

Нельзя создавать экземпляры `enum`.

Comment: А вы знаете, зачем перечисления нужны?

Comment: "Перечисления представляют набор логически связанных констант". Вам сюда: https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.8.php

Comment: А само перечисление вы неправильно создаете.

Comment: @Miron, передо мной книга Шилдта лежит, там больше чем на метаните написано, хоть на метаните хороший материал выкладывают)

Comment: Что делает конструктор `Food`?

Comment: нынче енам умеет расширяться? Странный вы какой-то язык изучаете =)

Comment: Никогда не видел, чтобы в enum изменения вносили.

Comment: Конструктор Food то покажите

Comment: @Igor, обавил конструктор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я скопировал ваш код, удалил метод `setTotalCost();` поскольку его реализации не было. И создал класс `Test` с методом `main`, добавил в `main` следующий код

```
Food food = new Food(true,false,false,false,false);
food.getValue();
```

И получил корректный вывод
[image: Корректный вывод]

Затем исправил метод `main` после поправки вопроса

```
Food food0 = new Food(false, false, false, false, false);
        Food food1 = new Food(true, false, false, false, false);
        Food food2 = new Food(true, true, false, false, false);
        Food food3 = new Food(true, true, true, false, false);
        Food food4 = new Food(true, true, true, true, false);
        Food food5 = new Food(true, true, true, true, true);
        food1.getValue();
```

И получил вывод такой, как указанно в вопросе, потому что все объекты food... ссылаются на разные массивы `Ration  ration[]`, но на один базовый объект, это можно увидеть в `debug idea`
[image: Корректный вывод]

Судя по вод этой строке кода

```
 private Ration  ration[] = Ration.values();       // Возвращаем массив, содержищий список констант типа Ration
```

Где мы не создаём новый экземпляр класса, а постоянно обращаемся к единственному экземпляру класса `Ration` поведение программы вполне закономерное

Comment: Подправил в топике, посмотрите, пожалуйста) Я так понимаю, что `enum` создается `единственный` на все экземпляры класса `Food`?

Comment: Я понимаю так, что раз создается 6 экземпляров класса `Food`, то и для каждого экземпляра класса создается свой отдельный `enum`. Выходит не так. Как так?

Comment: @n199a судя по **коду** и **скриншоту debug**, стало понятно, что класс enum имеет единственный экземпляр, и ваше понимание верно.

Answer (score 1):

Enum - абстрактный класс. Его объекты("завтрак", "обед", "ужин" и так далее) - `final`. Т.е. их значения после создания менять вы уже не можете. В вашем случае следует переписать ваш Enum как-то так:

```
public enum Ration {

BREAKFAST("Завтрак", false, 10), DINER("Обед", false, 20);

    private String name;
    private boolean include;
    private int cost;

    Kek(String name, boolean include, int cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.include = include;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
//При необходимости добавить геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Comment: @n199a, Вообще не понятно, зачем такие сложности когда есть банальный массив или коллекция?

Comment: @And не уверен, зачем это автору, но мы на проекте таким образом менеджерим наши кастомные эксепшены)

Comment: @And, надо всё попробовать, чтобы в дальнейшем знать, что целесообразно использовать, а что нет)

Comment: @n199a, ну так как вы используете, уж точно не надо использовать :).Я понимаю, когда енам используют для хранения опкодов или значений которые нужно будет динамить, но никак не такие жудкие реализации.

Comment: Как начало этого ответа и рассуждения про `final` согласуются с тем, что автор видит значения `true`?

Comment: @And, под жуткой реализацией вы понимаете то, как я реализовал `enum` или использование `enuma` в моей задаче?)

Answer (score 1):

> Почему при вызове метода `getValue()` класса `Food` я получаю все
>   true?

```
<телепатия>
```

Потому что после

```
Food food1 = new Food(true, false, false, false, false);
```

у Вас где-то есть код

```
new Food(true, true, true, true, true);
```

который Вы не показали.

```
</телепатия>
```

Все остальное понятно?

---

Вижу - непонятно.

`Ration.getValue()` возвращает массив одних и тех же объектов, сколько бы раз Вы этот метод ни вызывали. Изменив свойство любого из этих объектов, Вы увидите эти изменения во всех экземплярах `Food`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105849/discussion-on-answer-by-igor----enum----).